# Is there any possibility to view London from "The Gherkin"?

Tags: sightseeing, london, vantage-points

**30 St Mary Axe**, officially **The Swiss Re Building**, colloquially **The Gherkin** is one of the most prominent and tallest buildings in modern London, but it's proving difficult to find out for sure whether it has any public viewing platform or bar or restaurant accessible to the public, or any open days or such when an exception might be made to allow public viewing at certain special times.

[image]

There is a private restaurant and bar but not just anyone can go there.

**Is there any way for a normal member of the public to view London from this building?**

[image: The view that few are able to enjoy]

Comment: I did say **normal** member of the public, but normal for London may be a special case. (-:

Comment: Thanks for the photo Mark, I meant to come back and add one.

Comment: Often there are charity events for climbing tall buildings. For £30 you could climb the Gherkin in April 2011 to raise money for the Christchurch earthquake appeal. I think they did a climb of it for child cancer last year (2010). that and the London open house are about your two best bets(short of getting a job there)

http://www.londonopenhouse.org/ (not a sure bet but it has been opened in the past)

Comment: @Studart: I think this info is good enough for an answer.

Comment: Membership is £900 per annum plus an initial sign up fee of £300. :)

Comment: @Stuart - agree with hippietrail, take your comment and turn it into an answer :)

Comment: You can watch Woody Allen's movie [Match Point](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/m/matchpoint_01.html)

Comment: Wait, it isn't *actually* called the Gherkin? Huh..

Comment: It's a different building but you can now go to the top of the Shard: http://www.theviewfromtheshard.com/ "London's highest viewing platform at the top of Western Europe's tallest building"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Often there are charity events for climbing tall buildings.

For £30 you could climb the Gherkin in April 2011 to raise money for the Christchurch earthquake appeal.

I think they did a climb of it for child cancer last year (2010).

That and [the London open house](http://londonopenhouse.org/) are about your two best bets short of getting a job there)(not a sure bet but it has been opened in the past)
.

Comment: Just to warn you, the queue for the Gherkin at last year's Open House was the longest of any event and people were getting there at 4 am for a spot in line.

Comment: In previous years they have balloted tickets, last year I only went to mid level buildings like Battersea power station and it was 3 mile queue an hour before it opened.