# Can I view London from the top of its tallest building?

Tags: sightseeing, london, vantage-points

**One Canada Square**, incorrectly referred to as **Canary Wharf** is one of the tallest buildings in London, but it's proving difficult to find out for sure whether it has any public viewing platform or bar or restaurant accessible to the public, or any open days or such when an exception might be made to allow public viewing at certain special times.

[image: One Canada Square at Canary Wharf]

**Is there any way for a normal member of the public to view London from this building?**

Comment: I think that the tallest building that the public can access the top of in London is the "Walkie Talkie" - 20 Fenchurch Street. Though you do have to book in advance.

Comment: I have looked out of the 1 Canada Square roof which is semi-open with slats IIRC. It was the space where the A/C was running and we were in an office in the building early during its occupancy. I remember one of the lease conditions was that we had to leave the lights on 24/7 to make it look occupied ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The tower is used solely for office space and is not open to the
>   public. In the early days there was a viewing deck but this was
>   stopped due to concerns following IRA bombings.

(taken from [TallestSkyscrapers.info](http://www.tallestskyscrapers.info/london-one-canada-square.php))

However, it would appear that if you know somebody who works there, they are able to [take you on a tour of the building](http://www.randomwire.com/the-view-from-the-top).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

25 Canada square, the Citigroup building, which is [one of the tallest buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_buildings_and_structures_in_London) in London, does have a cafe on the 27th floor (I may be incorrect with the exact floor number), which is open to the public. It offers amazing panoramic views over London, and especially the Olympic sites and London City Airport.

Source: I used to work for Citigroup

Answer (score 4):

Citi's cafe is on the 36th floor. However, you will need to know someone who works there such that you can be there as their guest.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2010 the tallest building in London has been [The Shard (309.6m)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shard).

[image: The Shard, London]

Image © [User:Colin](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Colin) / [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) / [CC-BY-SA-4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

It has a [viewing gallery](http://www.the-shard.com/viewing-gallery/) at the top:

> London's highest and best view is situated at the top of The Shard, on floors 68, 69 and 72. At almost twice the height of any other viewing platform in the capital, it offers visitors unparalleled 360-degree views for up to 40 miles.

Unfortunately it's rather expensive, [advance tickets start from £25.95 (adult), £19.95 (child)](http://www.theviewfromtheshard.com/en/tickets-packages/ticket-information/).

Comment: Note that you can access the Shard's restaurant for free, which also has nice views (and the menu is moderately priced by London standards).

Comment: @JonathanReez that's useful to know. Is it near the top?

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question of whether one can see London from One Canada Square.

Comment: @JoErNanO, I'm answering the implied question of "can I get a view from the tallest building in London" (which used to be Canary Wharf but isn't any more). The spirit of the question rather than the letter of it. ;)

Comment: Ah, subtle nuance. I like that. :)

Comment: @AE 52nd floor: http://www.the-shard.com/restaurants/gong/. If I remember correctly the cheapest drink was around 5 pounds, which definitely beats having to queue and pre-purchase tickets for the viewing platform.

Comment: @JonathanReez: The pictures look like one risks being seated away from the windows, making the excursion somewhat pointless, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that restaurant isn't very busy during the daytime, so you're almost guaranteed a spot. In the night-time you can usually wait a bit to get a good seat from someone leaving.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68669/what-is-the-highest-viewing-spot-in-london-that-is-accessible-free-of-charge I've created a separate question to sort this out :)

Comment: Note that the Gŏng bar now has a minimum spend of £30 per person and so is not such a good deal if you don't actually want to drink.