# Vantage point for photography in Panama City

Tags: panama, vantage-points, panama-city

Yes, we have similar questions for [Manhattan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6869/101), [London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2798/101) and [Vancouver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/where-can-i-go-in-vancouver-thats-high-up-for-a-good-view-of-the-city-for-photo), but what about Panama City? It has a lot of skyscrapers, but WikiVoyage, Lonely Planet and TripAdvisor mention nothing about a publicly accessible high up observation deck, restaurant or the like. Seems like the views could be quite astonishing, with the Canal and all.

The tallest place I've found so far is [Ancon Hill](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g294480-d2513304-Reviews-Ancon_Hill-Panama_City_Panama_Province.html), yet the views are blocked by vegetation. There's a Hard Rock Hotel, but its Cafe is closed, and at the 2nd floor of the mall below.

[image]

Comment: When I was in Panama City half a dozen years ago it seemed these skyscrapers were all residential in a different area from the several areas that could be thought of as the "centre". Back then construction was just beginning though - it looks like a lot more pointy things than I remember.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, most online reviews on [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.my/ShowUserReviews-g294480-d2513304-r170000384-Ancon_Hill-Panama_City_Panama_Provinc.html) or other [local sites](http://www.panamainfo.com/en/ten-top-things-do-and-see-panama-city) also suggest Ancon Hill - others photos suggest that maybe the trees have grown since their shot and yours - or perhaps you need to get closer to the edge? :/

Another suggestion, however, is a different angle - the view from [Amador Causeway](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowUserReviews-g294480-d300879-r123182243-Amador_Causeway_Calzada_de_Amador-Panama_City_Panama_Provinc.html) or Calzada de Amador.  It's not a high-up view, but the view of the cityline from across the water, especially at night would be pretty great.

Some more searching, it looks like if you stay at the [Waldorf](http://waldorfastoria3.hilton.com/en/hotels/panama/waldorf-astoria-panama-PTYTPWA/local/CITY-attractions.html) there's a decent view, although that's outside my price range.

I also found [a great wee blog with some further ideas](http://2wanderinghearts.com/2013/12/01/panama-city-impressions-2/).  First, they suggest a walk down the Pacific boardwalk for amazing views of the skyline, and secondly, a trip up to Metropolitan Park.  The blog has photos from each of those, to give you some idea.