# Highest publicly accessible vantage point in Miami

Tags: usa, photography, miami

What publicly accessible tall building would offer a 360 degrees view of Miami, the way one can do so in [Manhattan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/what-publicly-accessible-tall-buildings-are-good-for-views-photography-in-manh), or [Vancouver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/where-can-i-go-in-vancouver-thats-high-up-for-a-good-view-of-the-city-for-photo)?

Comment: Not so much. Miami goes more for rooftop bars than observation decks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't too many opportunities to observe Miami from the top of a tall building from a "normal" observation deck. In fact, I am pretty sure none currently exist. Given the prevailing weather, rooftop bars are much more common.

Some of the highest of these are...

- [FIFTY Nightclub](http://www.fiftymiami.com/). This rooftop bar, on top of the Viceroy Hotel & Spa in Brickell, is a nightclub to be seen at. It does qualify by having 360 degrees of windows which you can look out, if you can find your way through the crowds, and if you can get in! The nightclub is open Friday and Saturday nights from 11pm to 5am.
- [The Bar at Level 25](http://conradhotels3.hilton.com/en/hotels/florida/conrad-miami-MIACICI/amenities/restaurants-the-bar.html) is quite a bit less exclusive, if you find that you can't get into FIFTY, or find staying out past midnight to be a problem. It's on top of the Conrad Hotel and opens at 11:30 am.
- Interested in more of a restaurant? Visit [Area 31](http://www.area31restaurant.com/) on the 16th floor of the Epic Hotel downtown. It's open for breakfast at 7 am so you can catch the sunrise over Biscayne Bay and Miami Beach.

However, some other opportunities may present themselves in the future:

- [SkyRise Miami](http://skyrisemiami.com/), a tower currently under construction in Bayside Marketplace, will feature an observation deck. But don't expect it to open until sometime in 2018.
- The proposed [Miami Innovation Tower](http://www.miamiherald.com/news/local/community/miami-dade/downtown-miami/article25536781.html) will offer several restaurants and an observation deck, but it's questionable whether this project will actually ever get off the ground.